# Agregar referencia de ensamblado en asp .net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Buen Día.

Tengo el siguiente Problema:
Recientemente migre mi proyecto web asp .net mvc 4 a mvc 5 todo salio normal a excepción de esta parte:

```
@if (Model.nombresAutocompletado.Count > 0)
{
    var empty = Model.nombresAutocompletado.ToArray();
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
                @Html.Raw(
                    string.Join(",\n\t", 
                        empty.Select(x => String.Format("\"{0}\"", x.nombre))
                    )
                )
            ];
            $('#asociarCliente').autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Mi error esta en `@Html.Raw(`, Pues cuando abro esa pagina me muestra error de compilación les muestro la captura.
[image: Error de compilación]

Si la página me dice este mensaje

> Mensaje de error del compilador: CS0012: El tipo 'System.Object' está definido en un ensamblado al que no se hace referencia. Debe agregar una referencia al ensamblado 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

No se como y donde agregar esa referencia soy nuevo en esto de asp.net mvc 5.

Comment: Al momento de compilar no me detecta que haya error alguno solo cuando accedo a la página desde el navegador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigando un poco mas profundo en google encontré una solución muy proxima
primero encontré en este [blog](http://smarrerof.blogspot.mx/2012/04/cs0012-el-tipo-systemdataobjectsdatacla.html) algo parecido a mi error.

Como no sabia donde exactamente poner la solución investigue otro poco mas y me encontré con este ejemplo:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <compilation>
      <assemblies>
         <add assembly="System.Data, Version=1.0.2411.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
   </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Y esto aclaro todo el problema.